# How to count and filter object in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models: in one, the user creates a post, and in the other, the likes of those posts are collected. Now I would like the number of these likes to be displayed on the post. Is there any way for all posts with the number of likes to be displayed on one template?

template.html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 mx-auto ">
        <ul class="list-group">
    {%for post in posts %}
    
      <a id="like_{{post.id}}" href="" class="like-link text-muted">
        +{% for every_like in likes_obj%}{%if every_like.liked_what == post%}{{every_like.count}}{%endif%}{%endfor%}

## At this point I would like to see the number of likes for each post it is assigned to, but unfortunately {{every_like.count}} returns
 nothing.

      </a>
    
    {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')

    paginator = Paginator(list, 10)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "post_form": PostForm(),
        "posts": page_obj,
        "likes_obj": Like.objects.all()
    })
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False)

class Like(models.Model):
    author_of_like = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_what = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(
        number_of_likes=Count('like')
    ).order_by('-date')

    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    return render(request, 'network/index.html', {
        'post_form': PostForm(),
        'posts': page_obj
    })
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.number_of_likes`, so you render this with:

```
{%for post in posts.qs %}
    <a id="like_{{post.id}}" href="" class="like-link text-muted">+{{ post.number_of_likes }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `list`, it overrides the reference to the [**`list`** builtin function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). Use for example `posts`.

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with a simple link (with `<a href="…">…</a>` tags).
> Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

Comment: This is what I ment! I didn't know there was such a solution. Thank you. Do I understand correctly that 'like' means a model with the name Like? Thank you for the tips too.

Comment: @fasfrtewqt2354r2edrq: yes, by default the name in reverse of a relation is the name of the model in lowercase (you can change that by specifying a `related_query_name` in your `liked_what` field). So here we can thus count the *related* `Like` objects for each `Post`.